# set control width to percentage of other control's width

Tags: silverlight, windows-phone-7

I'm trying to develop some kind of progress indicator control, basically this is just two borders. The inner one (green) needs to have width equal to some percentage of the outer one (gray) width. Here is my XAML:

```
<Border 
   Background="Gray"
   HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" />
<Border  
   Background="DarkGreen"
   HorizontalAlignment="Left"
   Width="..Something?" />
<TextBlock Text="{Binding Title}" />
```

My viewmodel has 2 properties:

```
public string Title {get;set;}
public double Progress {get;set;} //between 0 and 1
```

How do I set green border width to make it look like on the image below (it is hardcoded in xaml for this sample)?

[image: What i"m trying to get]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would use the System.Windows.Interactivity [`EventTrigger`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.interactivity.eventtrigger%28v=expression.40%29.aspx), along with [`InvokeCommandAction`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.interactivity.invokecommandaction%28v=expression.40%29.aspx), to update a `ProgressWidth` property in the view model, when the container [size changes](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.frameworkelement.sizechanged%28v=vs.95%29.aspx):

```
<Border 
   Background="Gray"
   HorizontalAlignment="Stretch">
    <i:Interaction.Triggers>
        <i:EventTrigger EventName="SizeChanged">
            <i:InvokeCommandAction Command="{Binding SetWidthCommand}"
                CommandParameter="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self},Path=ActualWidth}" />
        </i:EventTrigger>
    </i:Interaction.Triggers>
</Border>
<Border  
   Width="{Binding ProgressWidth}"
   Background="DarkGreen"
   HorizontalAlignment="Left"
   Width="..Something?" />
```

The `SetWidthCommand` would be a `DelegateCommand<double>`, and should simply set a new `ProgressWidth` property in the view model using the appropriate formula (ie, (double)parameter * Progress/100.0).

```
SetWidthCommand = new DelegateCommand(arg => (double)arg * Progress/100.0);
```

Comment: Thanks for pointing the approach! I'm using Caliburn.Micro so I simplified few things